# "MemberList.Source" not throwing exception when it should

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following models:

```
public class A
{
    public int a1;
    public int a2;
    public int a3;
    public int a4;
    public B b;
}

public class B
{
    public int b1;
    public int b2;
    public C c;
}

public class C
{
    public int c1;
    public int c2;
}

public class A_DTO
{
    public int a1;
    public int a2;
    public int a3;
    public B_DTO b;
}


public class B_DTO
{
    public int b1x;
    public int b2;
    public C_DTO c;
}

public class C_DTO
{
    public int c1;
}
```

And here are my objectives:

1. Map each member in source to the member in destination with the same name (including inheritance)
2. Create custom map for A.b.b1 --> A_DTO.b.b1x
3. Explicitly say that there is no mapping for A.b.c.c2
4. If there is an unmapped property in source that is not explicitly mapped AND cannot be mapped based on same name, throw exception

And here is the configuration I am using for that:

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<A, A_DTO>(MemberList.Source);
                cfg.CreateMap<B, B_DTO>(MemberList.Source)
                .ForMember(dest => dest.b1x, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.b1));
                cfg.CreateMap<C, C_DTO>(MemberList.Source)
                .ForSourceMember(src => src.c2, opt => opt.DoNotValidate());
            }
        );
```

And here is the test data I used:

```
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        A a = new A()
        {
            a1 = 1,
            a2 = 2,
            a3 = 3,
            a4 = 10,
            b = new B
            {
                b1 = 4,
                b2 = 5,
                c = new C
                {
                    c1 = 6,
                    c2 = 7
                }
            }
        };

        A_DTO aDto = new A_DTO();

        mapper.Map(a, aDto);
```

This meets all the conditions I listed above except the last one because `a4` does not exist on `A_DTO` and I still do not get an exception. (Whereas if I remove `.ForSourceMember(src => src.c2, opt => opt.DoNotValidate())`, it does throw exception for `c2`.)

Comment: Version of Automapper?

Comment: @BasilKosovan 8.1.1

Comment: How do you init mapper object?

Comment: @BasilKosovan just added that to the last code section in the post. (var mapper = config.CreateMapper();)

Comment: If you want to validate mapping config you can call config.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); Also you need delete .ForSourceMember(src => src.c2, opt => opt.DoNotValidate()); if you want see an exception. See screenshot http://prntscr.com/o3z29s

Comment: AssertConfigurationIsValid says that indeed a4 is not mapped.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu But it does not throw exception for `a4` during actual mapping. Whereas if I remove `.ForSourceMember(src => src.c2, opt => opt.DoNotValidate())`, it does throw exception for `c2`.

Comment: I've commented that line and the mapping works. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Now I tried it again after your comment and you are right, unmapped c2 does not throw an exception either. But why doesn't it? I am using MemberList.Source in the config.

Comment: Validation happens when calling AssertConfigurationIsValid. At runtime, if the mapping _can_ work, it will. This line was blurred because of maps created at runtime, but that feature is error prone and will be removed.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Is there a way to make it throw exception by deafult without the need to call AssertConfigurationIsValid? A configuration property maybe?

Comment: No, not by default. But I think you could write smth if you wanted. Like on BeforeMap call that code that validates the map. I don't know how well it would work, but you can give it a shot.